# default data-type of const-keyword is int-type?

Tags: c++, constants

One Book(Object Oriented Programming with C++ by E.Balagurusamy) says that

```
 const size = 10;
```

means

```
 const int size = 10;
```

but g++ compiler (version-4.6.1 in ubuntu) issues an error as

```
error: ‘size’ does not name a type
```

what should I conclude based on this?

1. g++ doesn't support the feature.
2. It is new feature. Latest g++ version supports it.
3. The statement is wrong. Data-type is mandatory with the *const* keyword.
4. Something else.

Comment: C's implicit `int` was removed already in C++98.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an error in the book ... you definitely must name a type or aliased type (i.e., a `typedef`) since C++ is a strongly-typed languages.

Here is what the C++03 specification states on objects, declarations and definitions:

---

Section 1.8/1:

> The properties of an object are determined when the object is created. An object can have a name (clause 3). An object has a storage duration (3.7) which influences its lifetime (3.8). **An object has a type** (3.9). The term *object type* refers to the type with which the object is created.

Then in Section 3.1/1:

> A declaration is a *definition* ... [note: the rest of the paragraph are exceptions to this rule and are omitted since they're not applicable in this case]

Then in Section 3.1/6:

> A program is ill-formed if the definition of any object gives the object an incomplete type

Finally, in Section 3.9.2/1 it states:

> ... the term *object type* (1.8) includes the *cv-qualifiers* specified when the object is created. The presence of a *const* specifier in a *decl-specifier-seq* declares an object of *const-qualified* object type; such object is called a *const* object. ...

---

So according to 3.9.2/1, `const` is a qualifier, not a type, and as-such, it has to qualify a valid unqualified type.  Secondly, in the example given, according to 3.1/1, the declaration of `size` is also a definition, and therefore the `size` object must have an associated type or the program is ill-formed according to 3.1/6.

Comment: Not error. It says so. And in some program examples, they used such statements.

Comment: I see I've been downvoted ... any reasons?  If there is a mistake, I think it helps everyone to know what that mistake is and get it fixed, rather than simply do a drive-by downvote.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but C is not a subset of C++ (although it comes close), and certainly there are features in C99 that don't exist until C++11 which is not in widespread use yet.

Answer (score 5):

Mr. Balagurusamy is wrong. Completely wrong. The *type* is compulsory, with or without `const` keyword.

You should stop reading this book. You should not read books by Yashwant Kanetkar also. I know that books by these authors are very popular among students of many universities in India.

I would suggest you to get an introductory book from this list:

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Oh my god! The C++ book list doesn't list E.Balagurusamy's book. We consider his books are as Bible for Programming Language.

Comment: @habeebperwad If Balagurusamy's C++ book contains a mistake such as claiming that 'const size' means 'const int size' then you should seriously reconsider your opinion of his book.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with: The statement is wrong. Data-type is mandatory with the const keyword.